# Applinks launching the app while the user is browsing the website

Tags: flutter

With the recent changes in App Links, on the latest version of Android, the user no longer has the disambiguation dialogue when clicking on an App Link supported URL (e.g. open with browser, open with X app).

However, what we noticed is that if the user is browsing on our website (e.g. example.com) and they click on an App Link supported link (e.g. example.com/flyer/), the app will now open instead of the user remaining on the website.

I did some testing with the Amazon app on the same device, and the experience on Amazon is different: if browsing on the website, the user remains on the website even if they click on an App Link supported link.

We'd like to have the Amazon experience, where App Links launch the app if the user clicks on links outside our website, but if a user is already browsing our website, they should remain in the browser.

Here's our assetlinks file What are we missing?

```
[
    {
        "relation": [
            "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
        ],
        "target": {
            "namespace": "android_app",
            "package_name": "com.example.com",
            "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
                "CA:C0:...."
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I've tried in the MainActivity with a referer, in the AndroidManifest by filtering more and in dart itself with the flow but nothing worked